# Power BI Cannot Connect to ADX via Azure B2B

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to connect to my Azure Data Explorer database in a NON-PRODUCTION azure tenant via Azure B2B.  My B2b user is an Admin on the ADX database as assigned within the Azure Portal and I can run queries fine from within the ADX Queries window.  When I sign in via Power BI and try to connect, it sees the ADX cluster but does not see the databases.  If I specify the database directly in the Power BI Connection window, I get the following error...

Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "Access to the resource is forbidden."

I was expecting access to the database but I do not think the ADX connector in Power BI can authenticate to an ADX database via Azure B2B credentials.  I think it can only pass native credentials to that specific Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post

[Azure Data Explorer Cluster - Details: "Access to the resource is forbidden."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802770/azure-data-explorer-cluster-details-access-to-the-resource-is-forbidden)

and that led me to this Azure Documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/referencing-security-principals

[image: 1]

Basically, this is what I did to solve the problem which is to add my user as an Azure Active Directory of my database. I don't understand why because I was already an admin user, but I hope this could be useful for someone else.

```
.add database MyDatabase users ('aaduser=MyUser@MyOrganization.com') 'User (AAD)'
```